# SQL (two Tables) Query most popular course

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having trouble returning the most common course
Question is: Write a Query to return the CourseName of the most common course

Tables

```
StudentCourses:
     StudentCourseID
     StudentID
     CourseID

Courses:
     CourseID
     CourseName
```

I have this

```
SELECT CourseName
From Courses c
WHERE CourseID = (SELECT Count(CourseID) AS Course_Value
                FROM StudentCourses
                Group BY CourseID
                Order BY Course_Value DESC
                LIMIT 1;
```

I know it isnt correct but am i correct using COUNT to find the most popular course correctly?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Top 1 CourseName 
FROM   Courses
JOIN   StudentCourses
  ON   Courses.CourseId = StudentCourses.CourseId
GROUP BY CourseName
ORDER BY Count(CourseName) DESC
```

Comment: Ha - you beat me to it, @Gordon :-)

Answer (score 3):

For this type of question, learn to use explicit `join` and `top`:

```
select top (1) c.courseid, c.coursename, count(*) as cnt
from studentcourses sc join
     courses c
     on sc.courseid = c.courseid
group by c.courseid, c.coursename
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want ties, then use `top with ties`.